# Curvilinear abscissa = radius * angle - Circular motion

Tags: physics, education, angle, curvilinear-coordinates

I would like to understand why:

$$ s(t) = r \, \theta(t) $$

where $s$ is the curvilinear abscissa, $r$ the radius and $\theta$ the angle in circular motion.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It is just how the planar angle $\theta$ is defined and measured. It is the ratio of the arc-length to the radius of a circle.

Comment: Hello @ShubhamJohri can you post any link where I can find this definition please?

Comment: Look at the 'Radians and Arc Length' section [here](https://www2.clarku.edu/faculty/djoyce/trig/angle.html)

Comment: Thank you so much @ShubhamJohri.